# How to set fill properties of Category axis marks to "no fill" in apache poi-5.0.0, I need to hide marks but with filling them without anything?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

tried following code but didn't work:

```
XDDFRunProperties textProperties = bottomAxis.getOrAddTextProperties();
     XDDFFillProperties noFillProperties = new XDDFNoFillProperties();
     textProperties.setFillProperties(noFillProperties);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, fillíng the tick marks using no fill is not the correct way. If you want hiding the tick marks, simply set `XDDFChartAxis.setMajorTickMark` to `AxisTickMark.NONE`. Same for `XDDFChartAxis.setMinorTickMark`, but that is the default anyway.

So:

```
...
bottomAxis.setMajorTickMark(AxisTickMark.NONE);
bottomAxis.setMinorTickMark(AxisTickMark.NONE);
...
```

See [XDDFChartAxis.setMajorTickMark](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartAxis.html#setMajorTickMark-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisTickMark-) and [AxisTickMark](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/AxisTickMark.html).